# Simple menu in Sitecore with C#/Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, sitecore

I am trying to build a simple menu based on the item structure in a Sitecore 6.6 solution. I am using Razor templates.

But i am stuck at the beginning. I need a menu where the that shows level 1, and all the items directly below that. Navigating to a page on level 2, will then display all the items below that, level 3, while still showing the levels above that.

Any pointers/snippets?

Answer (score 2):

You could probably do it something like this:

```
<ul>  
    @foreach (var child1 in Item.Children)  
    {  
         <li>@child1.Name  
            <ul>  
                @foreach (var child2 in child1.Children)  
                {  
                    <li>@child2.Name  
                        <ul>  
                            @foreach (var child3 in child2.Children)  
                            {  
                                <li>@child3.Name</li>  
                            }  
                        </ul>  
                    </li>
                }  
            </ul>  
        </li>  
    }  
</ul>
```

After this you can use CSS and some JavaScript to have the correct nodes visible and invisible. For instance, you could use the [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function of jQuery.

Comment: But how do i make sure that it is always the level 1 item that is beeing used in the first foreach no matter what level i am on in the navigation?

Comment: In stead of using Item.Children you can use the home item. 
From code, you could try Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext.StartPath)

(Or whatever other item you need to get it from)

Comment: @brother If this helped you, don't forget to mark it as answer :-) (and if it didn't let us know as well, of course)